# QField community plan: basemap vector data (localized layer as .shp or .gpkg format ) not permitted?

Tags: qfield, basemap

After I defined some vector data as basemaps, the project can no longer be synchronized to mobile devices. The error message 'useraccount's plan insufficient' appears. The error appears with both .shp and .gpkg files. Is it fundamentally not possible to use vector data as basemaps? Or does it just not work in the community plan?

Comment: Fundamentally base maps are rendered as raster data, though the source can be vector.  If you need a raster data source for qfield then you can use GeoPackage for this.

Comment: i dont need raster data source. raster data working fine in qfield cloud projekt as localized layer. qfield also supports vector data as a localized layer. but when using vector data as basemaps, the qfield cloud project is not synchronized